# Button Command only get invokes when pressing the second time

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a Button on my windows phone application. I have the Command Button binds to my RelayCommand in my ViewModel:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="aString"/>
```

I see DoSomethingCommand get invoked correctly when I press the Button.
But when the keyboard is launched, I need to click the button twice before I see the DoSomethingCommand get invoked. The first click causes the keyboard to close, the second  click invokes DoSomethingCommand.

Can you please tell me why there is a change in behaviors when the keyboard is open or not?

Comment: Did you try to see if Tapped and Click events are fired? Btw, i tried to reproduce, but worked fine for me. Maybe you'll share source code?

Comment: I also can't reproduce it. We need some source code or a repo to clone so we can investigate your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue today.

To explain it a bit better: a text box is focused, the keyboard is visible and a button is below the text box. Tapping this button the first time, unfocuses the text box and closes the keyboard. Tapping the button a second time, triggers the tapped event.

To solve this, I set `MyTextBox.IsEnabled` to `false` and then back to `true` in the next line. Setting it to false, unfocuses it. Setting it to true again, makes it usable again. The user won't notice, the keyboard closes and the button is tappable the first time.

Alternatively, one can set the focus to the button after leaving text box focus.